# Basic configuration page not responding

Tags: liferay-7, liferay-7.1

I have installed *Liferay 7.1* on my PC which has *Windows 7 (32 Bit)*.

I have installed Eclipse Neon IDE for it. I went according to the documentation provided by Liferay, but now after configuring my server, the initial page that opens up for basic configuration and database setup is not taking any input. I have reinstalled it many times but to no avail. I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong.

The configuration page opens up as follows:

[image: Basic configuration page]

I have installed *Liferay IDE 3.1.2.201709011126-ga3* and *liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.1.0-ga1-20180703012531655*.

Comment: Could you add the information of your browser as well?

Comment: i am using chrome

Comment: Could you check the developer console of chrome, if there is an error?

Comment: Error: 'YUI' is undefined.

Comment: Also sir i am using explorer not chrome as chrome is showing the following message:This Page Cannot Be Displayed
The system cannot communicate with the external server ( localhost ). The Internet server may be busy, may be permanently down, or may be unreachable because of network problems.

Comment: It is the _Internet Explorer_ (or short _IE_) - the Explorer usually refers to the _Windows Explorer_ (used for managing files). And the error message is quite obvious: your server is not started (correctly). Check in the IDE if the server is still started and check the console of the IDE for any error message. I'd guess that the IE still shows the cached configuration page but could not load the JavaScript files (due to the missing server).

Comment: The server is working properly.Also when i tried it on 64 bit machine,Liferay was properly working.Now i followed the exact same steps and  configuration page is not responding

Comment: I don't think that the server is "working properly" when Chrome is complaining abbout the connection. How do you mean this phrase? Did you check the server console for error messages?

Comment: i didnt get any error in the server console.